# What is the order of execution in try,catch and finally

Tags: java, exception

If we give return statement like this in try, what will be the order of execution

```
try{
--- ----
-----
return a;
}

catch{
}
finally{
}
```

Here what will be order of execution if there is return in try. Please let me know

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? This is trivial to test.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

`finally` always executes. If there is a `return` in `try`, the rest of `try` and `catch` don't execute, then `finally` executes (from innermost to outermost), then the function exits.

Comment: Not accurate. `finally` won't be executed if `System.exit()` is called or if the JVM crashes..

Comment: Yeah, it won't execute if you unplug the computer from the wall either. It's the same kind of situation, not really necessary to qualify.

Comment: @Widdershins Or if a dinosaur will eat your machine. But invoking `System.exit()` is a case you should take care of. (I agree about JVM crashing..)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Yeah, though honestly with the way `System.exit()` performs, it is essentially an internally-induced system-crash. Probably the dirtiest way to ever close any Java application, it seems to make no guarantees about how much could get done after it's called unless you have a shutdown hook that is very, very careful about `join()`ing your must-complete tasks. I have an application that has yet to dump many megabytes to file when `System.exit(0)` is called and it is either difficult or impossible to get it to finish. Honestly it would be better to not call `System.exit()` at all.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Looks like shutdown hooks `join`ing must-complete tasks are considered as blocking-trapped and will be terminated; you have to make sure your shutdown hooks actually do the work themselves. So I figured that out. I still think `exit()` is a bad way to shut down the machine and should be avoided if you have any better way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally is ALWAYS executed, after the evaluation of the return statement.

Comment: Well, the expression in the return statement will still be evaluated before the `finally` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a return in try, then control will go to finally block , execute the code present and then exit. So during this if in finally block there is any change to the any of the variable returned in try, and if that same variable is returned in finally then latest will be returned.

```
try {
             i = 11;
             return i;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally{

                i = 12;
                return i; --> This will be returned
            }
        //return i;


     }
```

But if there is only modification , no retrun in finally, the value returned in try will be the final value.

```
 try {
             i = 11; --> this will be returned
             return i;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally{

                i = 12; -- this will be executed

            }
        //return i;


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever might be the case `finally` will always execute.
Incase of sucessful execution of `try` it will not execute `catch` block. If `try` blocks throws exception then `catch` block will execute

Answer (score 0):

Normally order execution order of `try-catch-finally` is first `try`, then if `exception` trows and caught will `execute` the `catch`. If exception caught or not `finally` will  always execute.

If `return` in your `try`, execution in `try` will stop there and will execute `finally`. if `exception` throws and caught before that `return` normal execution order will follows.

Let's run following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr=getInfo();
    for(String i:arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static String[] getInfo(){
    String[] arr=new String[3];
  try {
      arr[0]="try";
      return arr;
  }catch (Exception e){
      arr[1]="catch";
      return arr;
  }finally {
      arr[2]="finally";
      return arr;
  }
}
```

Out put

```
try // return in try
null
finally // returning value in finally.
```

Now this out put explain the every thing you want. `finally` runs while there is a `return` in `try`.

If there a `System.exit(0)` in your `try`, `finally` is not going to execute.

Comment: You are specifying the order when you set the values of the array so naturally, that would be the order

Answer (score -1):

in `try-catch` handling, when you `return` something from a `try` block, it will goes out of the scope of `try-catch-finally`.. because catch block only accept what is thrown by `try`.. not the thing that is returned and now when you have returned from the try block it wont reach the try end and finally wont be executed, it will go out `try-catch-finally` block, back to your code.