# What is the order of execution with a javascript finally block, following a return in a try block

Tags: javascript

In relation to: [Java try-finally return design question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185340/java-try-finally-return-design-question)

This doesn't quite answer my question also may not be relevant since it's java and not javascript: [What is the order of execution in try,catch and finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538229/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-try-catch-and-finally)

I understand that putting a return in a `finally` block will take precedence over a return in a `catch` block, however how does the sequence events work with the following code?

```
function confusion(){
  var test = "a";
  try{
    return test;
  }
  finally{
    test = "b";
  }
}

console.log("Result", confusion()); //"a"
```

My general understanding of returning of anything is that control usually returns to the context of where the method is being called, so the fact that execution continues is kind've confusing to me.

In this scenario I thought it  might play out something like:

-Function set to return `test` -> `finally` changes value of `test` -> `test` is returned with updated value.

But instead it seems like some sort've state is held for the `try` block and `finally` misses the timing?

Comment: The value of `test` gets resolved when you `return` it in the `try` block. It stores the value, not the identifier. Subsequent rebinding of the identifier to another value doesn't change what's referenced to be returned.

Comment: It would be different if `test` was an object and you were updating a property, like `var test = {foo: "a"}`. So then when you return `test` and do `test.foo = "b"` in the `finally` block, the caller will see the mutation.

Comment: I've added a live example below to demonstrate what @user1106925 said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you `return` out of a `try` or `catch` block with an associated `finally` block, execution enters the `finally` block because that's the purpose of it: To handle common completion actions for the `try`/`catch`.

In your code, what happens as of the `return` is:

1. The value of `test` is read from the variable and set aside for use later.
2. Control passes to `finally`.
3. Code in `finally` changes the value of the variable `test` (which has no effect on the value that was set aside in #1).
4. When the end of the `finally` block is encountered, the function returns, using the value set aside in #1 as its return value.

This is covered in [The `try` Statement / Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-try-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the specification, and perhaps more readably in [`try...catch` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) under "The `finally` clause."

Note that the `finally` can interrupt the return process, by either throwing an exception, or returning a new value. If it does either of those things, it wins over the `return` in the `try` (or `catch`).

---

Side Note re your linked Java question: JavaScript's `try`/`catch`/`finally` works just like Java's except: 1. You can only have one `catch` block because exceptions aren't typed, and 2. JavaScript doesn't have Java's `try-with-resources` statement.

Comment: TJ, I just had a look at [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) for more information. I didn't find any. Can you link me to a link which gives an elaborate explanation of what you said.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: The 5.1 spec has been out of date for nearly two years. :-) I've added a link to the relevant part of the ES2016 spec (which will be obsoleted by the ES2017 spec in June).

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrating a comment made by @user1106925 that using a Javascript object instead of a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) produces OP's expected behavior.

```js
function lessConfusion(){
  var result = {test: "a"};
  try{
    return result;
  }
  finally{
    result.test = "b";
  }
}

console.log("result", lessConfusion()); //result.test="b"
```